# Bootstrap add-on weird behaviour with PHP error message

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to learn Bootstrap and was practicing with their components. It was working wonderfully, but when I tried to add some PHP error messages of my own I get an undesired effect on the `@` component:

[image: it expands]

```html
<div class="col-md-4 input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="someone@example.com" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>">
  <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?>
</div>
```

Why does it happen? I've tried to nest, style, and it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the undesired effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your paragraph outside the input group:

```
<div class="col-md-4 input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
  <input type="email" ...>
</div>

<?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/8k7mk9x6/)**